# How to activate barman_slot in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-12, barman, repmgr

I am using PostgreSQL cluster with Barman backup tools. I just recovered one of my backups. After recover, I found barman slot is inactive. Later, I deleted that inactive barman slot and created another barman slot.

Below is the command:

```
barman cron
barman check pg
```

It shows barman not initialized. Then, I ran  another command:

```
barman receiver-wal --reset pg
```

It shows receive wal position ahead of current WAL. So, in that case what is the solution?

Thanks In Advance for your support.

[image]